# Does repo sync pull the latest or pulls only the revision?

Tags: git, repo

I am new to repo and I am working on a project which involves fetching files from a manifest file using 'repo init' and the next step is 'repo sync'

One of the lines in manifest is

```
<project name="quic/qsdk/oss/boot/u-boot" path="qsdk/qca/src/u-boot" 
revision="2b8f00e696dc8a6340f4627e0a6b955153b69741" 
upstream="release/endive_preview_u2"/>
```

I understand 'repo init' will just initialize manifest files, etc and when 'repo sync' is executed it will clone the remote repository locally and fetch a revision or will it fetch the latest?

In the above manifest, since revision is mentioned the tree will be set to that revision. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks
Zer0_0ne

Comment: To fetch the latest only, you need to specify `--depth=1` in `repo init` first.

Answer (score 0):

I do not mention depth in the init command and only manifest file is passed as a parameter to init. After init when I perform sync, it performs a clone and sets the git repository to revision mentioned in manifest file.

In the above example, the local directory qsdk/qca/src/u-boot has the git repository cloned and repository is at  revision="2b8f00e696dc8a6340f4627e0a6b955153b69741"